# Put active class on active nav bar in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navigation bar like this:

```
  <li class="active">
    <a href="{% url 'website:wedding' %}">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li><a href="/todo_list/">To-do</a></li>

    <li><a href="/budget/">Budget</a></li>
```

Now, even if I am on To-do navigation bar the blue effect remains on Home nav only as there is `class=active`. How can I make it dynamic, so that if I am on To-do, the blue effect will comes on `To-do` nav bar.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.navbar').on('click','li',function(){
      $('.navbar').find('.active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
   });
})
```

Comment: It does work but when it instantly changes to the default `home` when the page is loaded fully.

Comment: I don't understand your comment... What is the problem exactly? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
});` this worked!